# Vue router changing the url but not the content, why?

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework

I'm intercepting a link click event. Then I check the domain name. If the name matches, then I take part of the URL and make the transition.

The problem is that the URL is changing, but the content is not. If you remove `event.preventDefault();` then the transition from the application to the site page will occur.

Can something be done about it? I need the app content to open.

```
getUrlFromHref(event) {
            if (event.target.tagName !== "A")
                return false;

            let url = new URL(event.target.href);

            if (url.host === process.env.VUE_APP_URL_HOST) {
                this.$router.push(url.pathname);
                event.preventDefault();
            } else if (!event.target.hasAttribute("target")) {
                event.target.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
            }

        },
```

Comment: We need to see how you have implemented vue-router.

Answer (score 1):

I added this code to router-view `:key="$route.fullPath"`. The solution is not obvious, but I hope it will help someone.